# Multiple vars_prompt tasks conditions when asking if install package

Tags: ansible

How can I prompt multiple questions before installation or gathering informations starts?

I tried this, but when I start it, it actually asks only for the second one `php73-mssql`, and ignores first question prompt.

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  roles:
    - ignum.php-mssql
  vars:

  vars_prompt:
  - name: install_php72_mssql
    prompt: "php72-mssql? yes/no"
    private: no

  tasks:
  - apt:
      name: php72-mssql
      state: present
    when: yes

  vars_prompt:
  - name: install_php73_mssql
    prompt: "php73-mssql? yes/no"
    private: no

  tasks:
  - apt:
      name: php73-mssql
      state: present
    when: yes
```

Comment: That is an amazingly malformed playbook, with all the yaml keys duplicated. I would suggest using a better editor than the one you used to construct that file. Both `vars_prompt` and `tasks` are lists, so there's no need to have such an illegal yaml file just to have multiple items under those keys. It's also very weird having `tasks:` and `roles:` in the same playbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this example could help you:

---

```
- hosts: Jenkins_cicd
  become_user: root
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "hostname"
      prompt: "Set hostname"
      default: "New-cicd-ansible-vm"
      private: no

    - name: "instance_size"
      prompt: "Instance size: / s-1vcpu-1gb / s-1vcpu-2gb / s-3vcpu-1gb / s-2vcpu-2gb / s-2vcpu-4gb / s-4vcpu-8gb / s-6vcpu-16gb /"
      default: "s-2vcpu-2gb"
      private: no

    - name: "image"
      prompt: "Please select vm image: / ubuntu-18-04-x64 / centos-8-x64 /"
      default: "ubuntu-18-04-x64"
      private: no

    - name: "token"
      prompt: "Set token key"

  roles:
    -  prod-create-digital-ocean-vm
...
```

Comment: not sure how, there is not multiple vars prompt with condition.. :/